# Calling stored function error in Java

Tags: java, oracle, function, stored-procedures, jdb

I am trying to call a stored function in Java. Function has no package, it's placed under user (schema) USER and returns a cursor. I tried twoways to call it and none of these works.

First one

```
Query query = coreDao.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("{call USER.gen_rephead_sm_task_report(?, ?) }");
query.setParameter(1, dateFrom);
query.setParameter(2, dateTo);
List<?> queryResult = query.getResultList();
```

I got a `not a procedure or not defined`

I also tried this approach with

```
select gen_rephead_sm_task_report(?, ?) from dual
```

as a createNativeQuery parameter but with the same result.

Second one

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();//javax.sql.DataSource
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call USER.gen_rephead_sm_task_report(?, ?) }");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);//oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes
statement.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dateFrom.getTime()));
statement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(dateTo.getTime()));
statement.executeQuery();
ResultSet set = ((OracleCallableStatement) statement).getCursor(1);
```

I got the `ClassCastException` on the last line (obviously OracleCallableStatement doesn't implement the CallableStatement). So which types shoud I use here?

Comment: Which driver do you use?

Comment: I am using `Oracle 11g` with `odbc-6.11.2.0.1.0`

Comment: try `statement.execute()` instead of `statement.executeQuery()`

Comment: are you connecting as the owner of the procedure or another user? also you have USER. in your code sample, i'm assuming that in your real code you don't have the string "USER" but the actual name of the schema? if you're connecting as another user, does that user have a package called as the same name as the schema object your calling? using SQLPLUS connect as the user you're connecting as in your JAVA code and do "DESC USER.gen_rephead_sm_task_report" what do you get (substituting USER for your real schema name of course)?

Comment: Can you check your driver is only available in one place? It should not be in WAR and under lib folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a link which solves my problem ([iDevelopment](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/jdbc/PLSQL_and_JDBC/RefCursorExample.java)). Here is what I used

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(TIMESHEET_QUERY);
statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
statement.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dateFrom.getTime()));
statement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(dateTo.getTime()));
statement.execute();

ResultSet set = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1);
```

Everything is straight from `javax.sql.*` so there is no need for Oracle Specific API.